# Getting the correct ROWCOUNT

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have done a union of 2 query.When i individualy take the rowcounts of the 2 queries it shows me 1504 rows and 15 rows respectively.But when i take a total rowcount ,i still get 1504 rows.Am i missing something here ?

The query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.sys_tenant_id
FROM SO_CTRL T1, S_BU T2
WHERE T1.SYS_TENANT_ID = T2.ROW_ID AND T2.CUST_STATUS_CD = 'Active' AND
    T1.OBJ_NAME = 'Opportunity' AND T1.CTRL_NAME != 'Primary Revenue Close Date'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT T1.sys_tenant_id
FROM SO_CTRL T1, S_BU T2
WHERE T1.SYS_TENANT_ID = T2.ROW_ID AND T2.CUST_STATUS_CD = 'Active' AND
    T1.OBJ_NAME = 'Opportunity' AND T1.CTRL_NAME = 'Primary Revenue Close Date' AND
    (T1.default_value_expr IS NULL OR LTRIM(RTRIM(T1.default_value_expr)) = ''))
```

Comment: Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

Answer (score 2):

One possible explanation for what you are seeing is the 15 rows in the second queries already exist as duplicates in the 1504 rows from the first query.

The `UNION` operator will filter out duplicates, so if you want to end up with a row count of 1519, you can try using `UNION ALL`.

Comment: thanks @Tim Biegeleisen...But this now brings in another question...as per 1st query :SELECT DISTINCT T1.sys_tenant_id
FROM SO_CTRL T1, S_BU T2
WHERE T1.SYS_TENANT_ID = T2.ROW_ID AND T2.CUST_STATUS_CD = 'Active' AND
    T1.OBJ_NAME = 'Opportunity' AND T1.CTRL_NAME != 'Primary Revenue Close Date';    //here i only want to consider distinct sys_tenant_id 's which has obj_name='Opportunity' and ctrl_name as anything other than    'Primary Revenue Close Date '...then why do i also get rows where  ctrl_name is 'Primary Revenue Close Date' ?? am i missing something out.